# Mostrar Popup con varios registros en Leaflet

Tags: csv, map, leaflet, popup, geojson

Se tiene un mapa en Leaflet con una serie de registros distribuidos en diferentes ciudades, algunas ciudades tienen varios registros (usuarios) con la misma ubicación, al hacer click en cada marker, solo muestra el popoup y la información con el primer registro del marker seleccionado.

Como podría mostrar el popup con la opción de ir visualizando cada uno de los registros asociados a dicha ciudad?

Adjunto screenshots con la visualizacin actual y parte del set de datos, donde se quiere puedan visualizarse todos los registros asociados a esa localidad.

[image: Popup actual mostrando solo el primer registro de la localidad]

[image: Parte de la BD con los registros asociados a la misma localidad]

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Amigo estas trabajando con folium que lenguaje estas utilizando para realizar el código

Comment: No estoy utilizando folium, trabajando con leaflet.js de cero, solo añadiendo bootstrap para diseño, de resto mas nada.